# Recursive algorithm to check whether the largest value in an array is larger than a given value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion

I did something like this:

```
compare(value, n)              //n is number of elements in array
    if ( n == 0)               //no more elements to compare with
       return false
    if ( array[n-1] > value)
       return true
    else
       return compare (value, n-1)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Do I need to sort the array recursively first and then compare the largest value with the given value?

Comment: Is it must to use recursion in the *better way*?

Comment: just remember the maximal element of the array and compare with it

Comment: @ArdentCoder yes

Comment: If the largest value is the first, you will return false when you should return true.  Otherwise your code works.  However if the array is large, I have concerns about the size of the call stack.  I personally would do a divide and conquer for that, but it will complicate the code and isn't what they are likely to look for.

Comment: @btilly *Re "If the largest value is the first, you will return false when you should return true."* When n is 1, `if (array[n-1] > value)` will handle it.

Comment: You can also try something like lazy dynamics: compare from end to begin, remember the element stopped comparing the last time you called this function and maximum on the current suffix. I guess the is no more optimal algorithm to get what you want. No need to sort, linear complexity in the worst case, `O(1)` additional memory

Comment: You can find the maximum value of the array with a single pass of the array in O(n). If more elements are being added to the array, this maximum value can be updated in O(1). After that you can return your compare function's result in O(1) with a single comparison.

Comment: Please provide an actual code example. Note that determining whether the largest number in the array is greater than a given value is the same as determining if *any* number in the array is greater than that value.

Comment: @ArdentCoder Oops, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

> Recursive algorithm to check whether the largest value in an array is larger than a given value

Your algorithm is correct, but you did not compare the *largest* value in the array, but any value larger than the given value. (Comparing the largest would require walking through the entire array.)

So you have to *proof* it, as comment:

```
if (array[n-1] > value)
    //     array[n-1] > value  /\  largest_array_value >= array[n-1]  =>
    // =>  largest_array_value > value 
    // (No need to search the entire array for the largest array value.)
```

And I would do instead `n == 0`:

```
if (n <= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm works correctly and it takes O(N) time to solve the problem. But since you are using recursion, when n is too large stackOverflow problem may arise. You can use loops to avoid that.

```
int compare(value, n) {

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     if (array[i] > value) {
        return array[i]; //You can also return 1 here.
     }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Regarding your question on whether to sort this array, it actually depends on your usage of this compare(value,n) function.

Sorting will take a O(N.logN) time complexity. So if you are going to use this function only 1 time or some constant K times, then your algorithm itself is good. No need for sorting. It will work on O(K.N) times which is essentially O(N).

But if you are going to use this compare function N times or more than that, then the time complexity becomes O(N^2). In that case it is wise to sort the array first and then check whether the first element is greater than value. Sorting takes O(N.logN) time and checking the first element takes O(1) time. So overall time complexity is O(N.logN). You can use merge sort or quick sort to get O(N.logN) sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the divide and conquer version.

```
compare_range(value, n, m):
    if m <= n
        return false
    if n+1 == n
        return array[n] == value
    mid = (n+m)//2
    return compare_range(value, n, mid) or compare_range(value, mid, m)
```

This still takes `O(n)`.  But the call-stack never exceeds size `O(log(n))`.